# opencv 4 on Ubuntu 18.04 with cuda 9.2

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cuda, ubuntu-18.04

I have compiled opencv 4 and Cuda 9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I tried to test a sample code with a OpenCV header file that I frequently use in my application . I am getting the following while compiling with nvcc:

```
    /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -o saxpy saxpy.cu --std=c++11 -I /opt/sensen/include/ `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
/opt/sensen/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h(1359): error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "CvSlice"

/opt/sensen/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h(1359): error: expected a ")"

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00004bc8_00000000-8_saxpy.cpp1.ii".
```

Has anyone else faced this issue? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The obvious answer is don't try and import that header into a CUDA compilation path

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I need to include this header file in my actual application. But I was getting this error, so I tried to write a simple code to test and still getting the same error.

Comment: You made yourself perfectly clear. But why do you need to import that file into CUDA code for? It contains nothing you can use within a CUDA kernel. I'm 100% certain OpenCV itself doesn't try and compile the contents of that header within any of its internal CUDA code. So why should you?

Comment: Ungh. Your answer @talonmies, is really snotty. I'm not directly including this file either, it gets lumped in when you do a cuda compile, and the error is unexpected. I'm getting it too. I'm using OpenCV 3.4.4.

Comment: In Core_c.h:

#ifndef OPENCV_CORE_C_H
#define OPENCV_CORE_C_H

#include "opencv2/core/types_c.h"

... etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as @mandar-sovani.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `OpenCV 3.4.3`. My solution to this problem: check in your cuda code (`.cu` files) which `#include` preprocessor directive is adding an OpenCV header. Then somehow modify your code to avoid that the said header is included into in your cuda code (`.cu` files).

Note: thanks @talonmies for the insight into the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Yo holmes, try replacing that weird block of code with this:

```
CV_INLINE  CvSlice  cvSlice( int start, int end )
{
    CvSlice slice = { start, end };
    return slice;
}
```

worked for me! (On Visual studio 2017)